# Inserting a CSV String into PostgreSQL Table

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, csv

I'm trying to Insert a CSV String into a PostgreSQL DB.  I cannot for the life of me find an answer that doesn't include a file.  I understand the

```
"\COPY table FROM 'path/to/csv.csv' CSV HEADER"
```

However I am using Node and have a javascript string including values like:

```
"1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7"
```

I have the table schema already and the csv strings that I am trying to insert will always match up.  However I cannot get it to insert from just a string and I don't have the option to do it from a file.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your destination data type? What insert query have you tried?

Comment: Hey @ethan-wolz, have you found the solution to this issue? I've just bumped with the same issue while performing a transformation over a stream of data before trying to insert it into PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
echo "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7" | psql -c "COPY table FROM STDIN DELIMITER AS ',' NULL AS ''"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a new Stream from my source stream, since each row of my source require multiple insertions and some transformations.

To be able to push it into PostgreSQL I had encode it back to ASCII.

Long Story Short:

```
rs.push(`${raw_id}, ${sensor._id}, ${value}, ${date}\r`.toString('ascii'));
```

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to give a full answer without more info, but if your table only has one column and you want to insert that list of numbers, you could do:

```
 INSERT INTO table VALUES (unnest(string_to_array('1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7', ', ')));
```

That will have one row per digit, and they will be inserted as strings.

I suspect that's not what your are after though, so you could try:

```
 INSERT INTO table (col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5, col_6, col_7) 
 SELECT a[1]::int, a[2]::int, a[3]::int, a[4]::int, a[5]::int, a[6]::int, a[7]::int
 FROM (SELECT string_to_array('1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7', ', ') a) stupid_obligitary_alias;
```

Ugly, but gets the job done and allows type conversion from text to integer.

I'm not going to attempt to do this for multiple rows at the same time.

string_to_array is documented at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html

Comment: You could also try it with a RECORD instead of an array. No idea how to do that: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html